# In maven multi-module, how to build only one module and its dependencies only if needed?

Tags: maven, multi-module

In maven 3 (3.3.9), I want to be able to build only one module in a multi-modules project, and if and only required also its dependencies (from the same project).

It's for integration in CI, so it must be idempotent but I want to avoid building again and again the same dep:

For example, say I have that project:

```
parent
 |- module1
 `- module2 // depends on module1
```

I want to be able to say `mvn [option] -pl module2 clean install` and have `parent` and `module1` only built and installed if they are not found in the correct version in available repository (local at least).

It seems that:

```
mvn -am -pl module2 clean install
```

also does a `clean install` on `parent` and `module1` each time.

The project structure is a given, so I can't split it in two with on one project (parent+module1) and on a second project (module2).

It seems to be a very common use case, so I certainly just missed the relevant documentation. Any body knows?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to build Snapshot- or Release-Versions? What do you mean by "correct version"? If module1 depends on the (now present) version of module2, you need to rebuild it if module2 changes, because it now has a new version of its dependency.

Comment: module2 depends on module1. In my case, module1 and parent don't change, but module2 can. So the use case should be identical for snapshot and version (AFAIK).

Comment: Sorry, I misread your dependency order. But I don't understand your requirements yet. `-am` leads to module1 being built if module2 is built (as you said). When exactly do you want to do that (and when not)?

Comment: First I suggest within a CI environment to build the whole project (all modules) without exceptions...The questions is if you really like to have/need a multi module build or if it would be better having separate projects ?

Comment: I want to build `module1` if and only if it is not available in local repos for required version. I want to always be able to say `mvn ..... module2` and have `module1` built only if it is not yet in local repos